# Placeholder tags using bootstrap 3.2 does not fit properly in input box

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I was hoping if someone can inform me what I need to do to get the placeholders in the input box for the dates to fit properly.

I've been playing around with the bootstrap code, but can't fit it in properly.

Here is my screen shot:
[image]

Here is my code using horizontal forms:

```
<div class="container nopadding">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-sm-2 control-label" for="txtPISIQueueManufacturer">Manufacturer:</label>
        <div class="col-sm-2">
            <input type="text" class="form-control height-auto" id="txtPISIQueueManufacturer" placeholder="Enter Manufacturer" />
        </div>
        <label class="col-sm-2 control-label" for="ddlPISIQueueRequestType">Request Type:</label>
        <div class="form-group col-sm-3">
            <select class="form-control" id="ddlPISIQueueRequestType">
                <option>Shipping Information</option>
                <option>Option 1</option>
                <option>Option 2</option>
                <option>Option 3</option>
            </select>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group col-sm-8">
        <label class="control-label col-sm-offset-1">Requested Date:</label>
        <input class="height-auto" id="dtePISIQueueRequestedFromDate" placeholder="From Date" type="text" />
        <span class="label label-default">To:</span>
        <input class="height-auto" id="dtePISIQueueRequestedToDate" placeholder="To Date" type="text" />
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Seems to render just fine when I pop your code into Bootply: http://www.bootply.com/hOChMyE1qV

Comment: You're right... It's just an IE quirk. I brought it up in Firefox and looks just fine.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem lies in your css properties for your input type["text"] or date or any of the sort. Use your browser inspector and look for an excessive padding or line height in your input fields.